# Joomla: error while saving form in custom view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-component

I have created a custom component with form to update prices of four product to be displayed on frontend.

My main controller code is here:

```
public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false) {

    require_once JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers/calculator.php';

    $view       = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('view', 'pricetable');
    $layout     = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('layout', 'edit');

    JFactory::getApplication()->input->set( 'layout', $layout );
    JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('view', $view);
    JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('id', 1);

    parent::display($cachable, $urlparams);
    return $this;
}
```

id is set to 1 so it loads only first row from database.

code for pricetable container is:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->view_list = 'pricetable';
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Now in admin backend the form is loaded as desired with the first row of data. 
When I try to save the form it is redirected to `administrator/index.php?option=com_calculator&view=pricetable` and error is:

> Error: You are not permitted to use that link to directly access that
>   page (#1).

my form action is:

```
<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_calculator&task=pricetable.edit&id='.(int) $this->item->id); ?>
```

Please suggest where I am doing wrong. It is third day I'm scratching my head. :(

Comment: and if you set form action as `<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_calculator&view=pricetable&task=pricetable.edit&id='.(int) $this->item->id); ?>`?

Comment: Nothing happens with this as well. What I think is the problem with pricetable controller. Isn't there any way to redirect component to `administrator/index.php?option=com_calculator&task=pricetable.edit&id=1` on its first load.

Comment: i think u can update data on same page u are. nowhere else. so just make this field empty (`action`) to make sure u're staying on same page...

Comment: @StasGrin keeping action empty saves the form data to new instance, but do not update the existing one.

Comment: that's why? u can do updating actions (or calling them) inside your code whenever it is. New instance or update new - add one more `IF` and `hidden` input with for example `name=task value=update`

Comment: Using empty `action=""` and adding a hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />` worked. You saved my life @StasGrin. Thank you.

Comment: oh.. that was so obvious, that i don't believe it's solution. posted as answer for closing this qestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do updating actions (or calling them) inside your code whenever it is. 
New instance or update new - just add one more `if` in code and `hidden` input on form. For example:

`<input type="hidden" name="task" value="update" />`